# changing cursor to block in insert mode on Neovim

Tags: neovim, cursor, macos, iterm2

I am a new neovim user. I am currently on MacOS, and using iTerm as my terminal emulator. I am using Neovim 0.4.3.

I would like to configure my neovim in such a way that the cursor in insert mode is a bit fat. Right now its very thin. If that cannot be done, can I somehow configure Neovim in such a way that I can use block cursor in insert mode as well?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: see ```:h 'guicursor'```

Answer (score 8):

enter this command in vim to use block cursor in insert mode:

```
:set guicursor=i:block
```

Answer (score 0):

If using a lua config write:

`vim.opt[guicursor] = ""`

Comment: I'm using Neovim 0.9.1 and this only worked for me if I change it to use a string like this: `vim.opt["guicursor"] = "" `. Lua also accepts single quotes as strings too

Comment: `vim.opt.guicursor = ""` is the preferred style.